# virt-install blocked in domain connection

Tags: virtual-machine, centos7

I tried to install Centos 7 guest vm using the virt-install command with the local ks file but I am stuck in the "Connected to the domain" state
Can you help me please
this is the output from terminal:

```
[klaude@localhost ~]$ LANG=C sudo virt-install --connect qemu:///system \
> --name centos7-ks \
> --ram 2048 \
> --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/centos7-ks.qcow2,size=10 \
> --vcpus 2 \
> --os-type linux \
> --os-variant centos7.0 \
> --network bridge=virbr0 \
> --graphics none \
> --location /var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1804.iso \
> --initrd-inject=/home/klaude/Documents/ks1.cfg
[sudo] password for klaude: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for klaude: 
WARNING  Did not find 'console=ttyS0' in --extra-args, which is likely required to see text install output from the guest.

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                          |  354 B  00:00:00     
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                                                                            | 5.9 MB  00:00:00     
Retrieving file initrd.img...                                                                                                                         |  50 MB  00:00:00     
Allocating 'centos7-ks.qcow2'                                                                                                                         |  10 GB  00:00:00     
Connected to domain centos7-ks
Escape character is ^]
```

Comment: Please re-run the command with the locale `C` so that the output is in English.

Comment: i changed the output of the command in english "LANG=c"